# Passing Arguments from wrapper script to the binary being called in cshell

Tags: bash, unix, csh

I have a wrapper run script lets call it wrap_app.sh
All it does is call some binary

```
./mybinary --run-test --run-allnew "$@"
```

Now when I invoke it I can provide it additional arguments in bash

`./wrap_app.sh --run-new-arg`

and these arguments will be passed to mybinary

Now I am trying to do the same thing in csh and it doesn't seem to be working.

Can Anybody provide the equivalent for $@ in csh?

Comment: You should stay with sh/bash/ksh family of bourne-compatible shells... have a look at : [link]http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `tcsh` the list of arguments to a script is `$*`